# Stripe error: Plan already exists

Tags: payment-processor, stripe

I am getting the following error on a Stripe page that is set up to handle recurring membership contributions.

I'm wondering if people have seen this before and if anyone has pointers on what the solution might be.

```
Error Oops! Looks like there was an error. Payment Response: 
Type: invalid_request_error
Code: resource_already_exists
Message: Plan already exists.
```

I saw that there is a plan_id column in civicrm_stripe_plans but am not familiar enough with Stripe to know what to do with it (and Googling didn't turn up very much).